# Using diff() inside a function creating error and not executing

Tags: r, xts, zoo

My reproducible data looks like this-

```
data <- rnorm(16)
timeStamp <- as.POSIXct("2019-03-18 10:30:00") + 0:15*60
Rf <- xts(x = data, order.by = timeStamp)
colnames(Rf) <- "R"

Rf[4:5]$R <- NA
Rf[8:9]$R <- NA
Rf[13:14]$R <- NA

omit.Rf <- na.omit(Rf)
```

My goal is to label the consecutive series chronologically and the following code works-

```
diff.omit.Rf <- diff(index(omit.Rf))
diff.omit.Rf <- append(1, diff.omit.Rf)
initNum <- 1
for (i in 1:length(omit.Rf)){
  if (diff.omit.Rf[[i]] == 1){
    omit.Rf$opNum[i] <- initNum
  } else {
    initNum <- initNum + 1
    omit.Rf$opNum[i] <- initNum
  }
}
```

And I get this output-

```
                     R              opNum
2019-03-18 10:30:00  0.89262137     1
2019-03-18 10:31:00  0.50428310     1
2019-03-18 10:32:00 -0.00040488     1
2019-03-18 10:35:00  0.10126335     2
2019-03-18 10:36:00  0.48726498     2
2019-03-18 10:39:00  1.05075049     3
2019-03-18 10:40:00 -0.25495699     3
2019-03-18 10:41:00  0.89257782     3
2019-03-18 10:44:00 -1.25474533     4
2019-03-18 10:45:00  0.55393767     4
```

Unfortunately, when I use the same code to create a function it gives me following warning and do not execute the function.

```
Error in diff.omit.Rf[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

The code for the function I made-

```
opTimeFun <- function(dataToDeal){
  diff.data <- diff(index(dataToDeal))
  diff.data <- append(1, diff.data)
  initNum <- 1
  for (i in 1:length(dataToDeal)){
    if (diff.data[[i]] == 1){
      dataToDeal$opNum[i] <- initNum
    } else {
      initNum <- initNum + 1
      dataToDeal$opNum[i] <- initNum
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone help to solve this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a shorter version without a `for` loop using `diff` and `cumsum` to create series.

```
opTimeFun <- function(temp) {
   cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(index(temp)) > 1))
}

omit.Rf$opNum <- opTimeFun(omit.Rf)
omit.Rf

#                             R opNum
#2019-03-18 10:30:00 -0.1952424     1
#2019-03-18 10:31:00  0.8429390     1
#2019-03-18 10:32:00 -0.2429325     1
#2019-03-18 10:35:00  1.3471985     2
#2019-03-18 10:36:00 -0.7869906     2
#2019-03-18 10:39:00  0.5220991     3
#2019-03-18 10:40:00 -1.9884231     3
#2019-03-18 10:41:00 -1.8417666     3
#2019-03-18 10:44:00  1.5586149     4
#2019-03-18 10:45:00  3.5704500     4
```

---

We can break the function step by step to understand how it works.

`diff` returns the time difference in minutes.

```
diff(index(omit.Rf))
#Time differences in mins
#[1] 1 1 3 1 3 1 1 3 1
```

We compare it with 1 minute and find out values which are greater than 1 minute

```
diff(index(omit.Rf)) > 1
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Since `diff` returns value which is of length 1 less than the original vector we add a default value `TRUE` at the beginning of the vector.

```
c(TRUE, diff(index(omit.Rf)) > 1)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

and now take cumulative sum of this logical vector which would increment at points where the value is greater than 1.

```
cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(index(omit.Rf)) > 1))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4
```

---

As far as the original function is concerned, it works properly but we need to explicitly `return` the object back from the function. So the below function should work.

```
opTimeFun <- function(dataToDeal){
  diff.data <- diff(index(dataToDeal))
  diff.data <- append(1, diff.data)
  initNum <- 1
  for (i in 1:length(dataToDeal)){
     if (diff.data[[i]] == 1){
        dataToDeal$opNum[i] <- initNum
     } else {
        initNum <- initNum + 1
        dataToDeal$opNum[i] <- initNum
     }
   }
   return(dataToDeal)
 }

opTimeFun(omit.Rf)
```

Comment: Can you kindly explain the cumsum code? and also if possible can you reflect on the mistake in my code? I am very novice in coding and just want to learn. Mainly, in my code, i do not understand why the same codes working outside the function but not inside.

Comment: @user11841472 I added some explanation of the code as well as the reason why your code didn't work. Hope it is helpful.